# Python3: Loop over objects and add attributes to an array or object

Tags: json, django, python-3.x, for-loop

I'm trying to loop through some objects and add certain attributes to an array to be sent back as JSON to the view:

```
data = {}
camera_logs = CameraLog.objects.filter(camera_id=camera_id)
for log in camera_logs :
    setattr(data, 'celsius', log.celsius)
    setattr(data, 'fahrenheit', log.fahrenheit)

return JsonResponse(data)
```

I'm quite new to Python, so I'm not sure if I'm even on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing Python dictionaries is much easier than using setattr. 
You have two options. Either create a dictionary with IDs as Keys or just a simple list.

```
import json

data = {}
camera_logs = CameraLog.objects.filter(camera_id=camera_id)
for log in camera_logs :
    data[log.id] = log.celsius

return Response(json.dumps(data))
```

in above solution you will have a dictionary with ID of CameraLog as a KEY, and as value you will have celsius. Basically your json will look like this:

```
{
   1: 20,
   2: 19,
   3: 21
}
```

Second approach is to send a simple list of values, but I guess you would like to have info, what camera had what temp

```
import json

data = []
camera_logs = CameraLog.objects.filter(camera_id=camera_id)
for log in camera_logs :
    data.append(log.celsius)

return Response(json.dumps(data))
```

---

*Edit to an answer*

If you wish to have a list of dicts, make something like this:

```
import json

data = []
camera_logs = CameraLog.objects.filter(camera_id=camera_id)
for log in camera_logs :
    data.append({
        'camera_id': log.id,
        'celsius': log.celsius,
        'fahrenheit': log.fahrenheit
     })

return Response(json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: Very helpful. I see that I wasn't totally off track. Now, how would I add multiple attributes of `log` to the `data` object?

Comment: I'm getting `Object of type 'Decimal' is not JSON serializable` as the response

Comment: I've updated my answer. If you have Decimal is not JSON serializer you have to use for example simplejson - which does well with Decimal. Because python json has troubles with Decimal fields. Than you can just make `import simplejson as json` and use it as above

Comment: Ah, I just cast it as `float` ... my last issue is that the object that is being creating is being escaped like: `\"camera_id\"`

Comment: Oh my bad, it's double wrapping json, I did not see it was JsonResponse. Either you make a Response(json.dumps(data)) or you make JsonResponse(data)

Answer (score 0):

You can enhance your query by only selecting the attributes that you need from a queryset using `.values_list`.

```
import json

camera_logs = CameraLog.objects.filter(camera_id=camera_id).values_list(
    'celsius', 'fahrenheit')
data = [{"celcius": cel, "fahrenheit": fahr} for cel, fahr in camera_logs]
return Response(json.dumps(data))
```